Jest testing an MUI Dialog
I have an MUI dialog which I am trying to test as part of a larger test case for the dialog's parent.  There are a few steps before the dialog can be opened.  First, a Material-Table must be rendered.  Then an action in the table's action column must be clicked.  Clicking on this action will call a function which runs a fetch request before setting the Dialogs open prop to true.
In my test, I am mocking the table data and the data which is passed into the dialog.  I know the mocks are working as my other tests are passing.
Here is my test:
it("clicks the edit icon and opens the dialog", async () => {
    render(<ParentComponent />);
    const editRow = document.querySelector("#edit");
    await act(async () => {
        fireEvent.click(editRow);
        expect(useData().fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data.Id);

        const dialog = within(await screen.findByRole("dialog"));
        expect(dialog.getByText("ID:")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});

The test fails at:
Unable to find role="dialog"
... A really ling HTML output ...
> 112 | const dialog = within(await screen.findByRole("dialog"));

Here is the function where the dialog is opened:
const openDialog = async (Id, badge, name) => {
    await fetchData(Id);
    setOpen(Id);
};

Here is how the dialog is called within its parent:
<MyDialog
    open={open}
    data={data}
    onClose={handleClose}
/>

And here is the dialog:
import { styled, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogTitle } from "@mui/material";
const CustomDialog = styled(Dialog)(() => ({
    "& .MuiDialog-container": {
        "& .MuiPaper-root": {
            width: "40rem",
            height: "29rem",
        },
    },
}));

export default function MyDialog(props) {
    const { open, onClose, data } = props;
    return (
        <CustomDialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
            <DialogTitle>
                ID: {data?.Id}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </CustomDialog>
    );
}


A few things that I would check:  Does the editRow selector give you a proper element when fireEvent.click() is executed?  Additionally, the use of findByRole within an act() is essentially a callback function within a callback function.  This may cause some issues.  I would look at moving everything except the fireEvent.click() out of the act callback.

This link react-testing-library might help

The "really ling HTML output" will include which elements and roles it did find, which apparently doesn't include anything with the dialog role. There's not much we can add to that - use a role that the element you want to select does have, or make sure the element has the role you're trying to select by.
